# Python AttributeError: I defined a class, but when I run it , it showed object has no attribute

Tags: python, class, attributes

In my GlobalObject.py Python file, I defined a class named ProjectVarible:

```
import os
import pandas as pd

class ProjectVarible:
    def __init__(self):
        self.cwd = os.getcwd()
        self.InPath = self.cwd + '\\data\\'
        self.OutPath = self.cwd + '\\result\\'
        self.ipoPreQuarter = 11
        self.screenDataPre = 19
        self.assetPoolName = 'AllAStock'
        self.indicator = 'amt'

    def show(self):
        print('current set:')
        print('pastDataLen = ', self.pastDataLen, end=';\t')
        print('recentDataLen = ', self.recentDataLen, end=';\t')
        print('assetPoolName = ', self.assetPoolName, end=';\t')
        print('indicator = ', self.indicator)

def which(series,value):
    DF=pd.DataFrame({'index':range(len(series)),'value':series})
    resultdf=DF.loc[DF['value']==value,:]
    return list(resultdf['index'])
```

When I create a ProjectVarible object named PVariable, the InPath attribute works well:

```
from GlobalObject import *
PVariable=ProjectVarible()
path=PVariable.InPath
path
Out[143]: 'D:\\PycharmProjects\\Entropy Capital\\Financial Indicator\\Fundamental.2\\data\\'
```

But when I call the ipoPreQuarter attribute, It didn't work and return an  AttributeError:

```
ipoPreQ=PVariable.ipoPreQuarter
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2862, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-144-abaa7a33b94f>", line 1, in <module>
    ipoPreQ=PVariable.ipoPreQuarter
AttributeError: 'ProjectVarible' object has no attribute 'ipoPreQuarter'
```

[image]

what's wrong?, how can I use these attributes?

Comment: Did you add `ipoPreQuarter ` recently or was it there from the beginning? Check for and delete any `.pyc` files in your directory (including `__pychache__`and try again

Comment: thank you very much! when I delete the .pyc files in my directory, It works!